# Code produces stack overflow exception only in Release configuration on VC++ 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, crash, stack-overflow

this code works fine in `VC++ 2015 Debug` configuration ... However it always throw stack overflow exception in `Release` .. Particularly when enabling **Code Optimization "/O2"** ..

When I traced deeply into this problem .. I found the compiler is reusing the first `Sequence` Object in the next line `(x >> x).Check(&j);`

I cannot figure out what is the problem .. and how to avoid such a behavior

```cpp
typedef char Char;

class TokenizerInterface
{
public:
    virtual bool Check(Char**) = 0;
}; 

class RulesSet : public TokenizerInterface
{
    TokenizerInterface& tok;
    public:

    RulesSet(TokenizerInterface& tok) : tok(tok) {}

    virtual bool Check(Char** x)
    {
        return tok.Check(x);
    }
};

class Sequence : public TokenizerInterface
{
private:
    TokenizerInterface& vtok1;
    TokenizerInterface& vtok2;

public:
    Sequence(TokenizerInterface& tok1, TokenizerInterface& tok2) :vtok1(tok1), vtok2(tok2) {}
    virtual bool Check(Char** x)
    {
        Char* start = *x;

        if (!vtok1.Check(&start) || !vtok2.Check(&start))
            return false;

        *x = start;
        return true;
    }
};


class In : public TokenizerInterface
{
private:
    Char* str;
public:
    explicit In(Char* str) : str(str) {}
    virtual bool Check(Char** x)
    {
        if (strchr(str, **x) != 0)
        {
            (*x)++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

inline Sequence operator >> (TokenizerInterface& t1, TokenizerInterface& t2)
{
    return Sequence(t1, t2);
}

int main()
{

    char* j = "OSOS";

    RulesSet x = In("O") >> In("S");
    (x >> x).Check(&j);//<<CRASH

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x.tok` is a dangling reference, referring to a temporary (produced by `In("O") >> In("S")`) that has since been destroyed. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: `(x >> x)` looks like a problem to me as well, slices the RulesSet to a Sequence.  That's the one that blows the stack afaict.  Curious that this works in a non-optimized build.  Hmm.